# Apply change text color to specific header style

Tags: javascript, html

Hi does anyone know how to word this script so that it specifically targets my home header style and not the global header style,

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){       
    var scroll_pos = 0;
    $(document).scroll(function() { 
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(scroll_pos > 50) {
            $(".pcnav.navlinks").addClass("navblacktext");
            
        } 
        else {
            $(".pcnav.navlinks").removeClass("navblacktext");
            
        } 
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header_home">

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"><div><img src="IMAGES/Logo- 
    Icon.png" class="logo" width="48px"></div>

    <div class="navwrap">
    <a class="pcnav navlinks" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="pcnav navlinks" href="#services-target">Capabilities</a>
    <a class="pcnav navlinks" href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="pcnav navlinks" id="aboutus" href="about-us.html">About</a>
    <a class="pcnav navlinks" href="#contact-target">Contact</a>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">

    <button class="hamburger hamburger--collapse is-active" 
    type="button">
    <span class="hamburger-box"><span class="hamburger-inner"></span</span>
    </button>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </header>
```

Would appreciate any help! the other headers are wrapped in "header_global" instead of "header_home".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just amend your selector to only select elements within `.header_home`.

```
$(".header_home .pcnav.navlinks").addClass("navblacktext");
```